# PHP to pseudocode?

Tags: php

Is there a tool for converting PHP source to pseudocode automatically?

I implemented some algorithm and i want to have its standard independent-language pseudocode. please help me to find the tool,if any.

Edit:

for example, the PHP source is:

```
$A=array('b');
array_unshift($A,'a');
print_r($A);
```

and its pseudocode is such as:

```
Define array A with first element 'b'
Prepend string 'a' to the beginning of array A
Print all elements of array A to output
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not Google. It's not even Bing, which is sort of like a search engine.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, i googled first, but i didn't find

Comment: Also what could you possibly want that for? Please give an example. Show what code you would want to be transformed into what type of pseudocode. Some form of BASIC or code description? (Also to see if you understand what pseudocode means.)

Comment: @ahoo: Failure to Google properly is not reason to ask for searching help on a programming Q&A.

Comment: @mario, see my example, please

Comment: Well, I don't think such a tool exists. One of the PHP parsers could be used for it. But the code description you expect is way too high level. That would require intimate knowledge of what which function does, and specific textual representations for special cases (e.g. your array with just one "first" element). That doesn't seem feasible to me.

Comment: @mario thanks for your attention to me

Answer (score 2):

There's no such language as "pseudo-code" nor language independant pseudocode. What you could do is rewrite the algorithm in C. That way it will work almost in every environment.
Edit:

Pseudocode is not for universal algorithms, is for humans to read and understand, nothing more.